# Proving uniqueness in $\mathbb{C}$ of function $f$ verifying $\hspace{0.2cm}f(u+v)=f(u)f(v),\forall u,v\in\mathbb{C},f(1)=e$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I am trying to prove that the complex exponential function 
$$exp\colon\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C},z \mapsto exp(z):=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}$$
is the unique continuous function $\hspace{0.2cm} f\colon \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(u+v)=f(u)f(v), \forall u,v\in\mathbb{C}$ and $f(1)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}$.

I have already proved that the exponential satisfies this condition. My difficulties are only in proving the uniqueness. I have tried several ways to prove it, but not a clue how to do it. Notice the definition of the exponential function I am using.

Any ideas?

Comment: The Zero function also satisfies the condition.

Comment: Edited, added the hypothesis $f(1)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}$.

Comment: I see no easy way; it is easy if you assume $f$ differentiable at a point.

Comment: @egreg do you disagree with my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: After @egreg pointed out some flaws in my reasoning, I think I've found a counterexample: Let $\zeta \in \mathbb{C}$ be arbitrary. Then $f_\zeta(z) := \exp(\Re(z)+\zeta \cdot\Im(z)i)$ defines a continuous function on $\mathbb{C}$ with $f(1) = e$ and $f_{\zeta}(u+v) = f_{\zeta}(u)\cdot f_{\zeta}(v)$. But for $\zeta \neq 1$, we have $f_{\zeta} \neq \exp(z)$.

Comment: There are $n$ distinct roots of $f(1)$ in the complex numbers. And of every other nonzero number. It's by no means obvious that $f$ maps $i$ to a purely imaginary number.

Comment: @egreg ah yes, that's of course right.

Comment: @egreg I'd appreciate if you let me know if I messed up again.

Comment: It seems good, now. Of course this is not differentiable (in complex sense) unless $\zeta=1$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a false result, so you can't prove the uniqueness.

Take for instance $f(z)=0$ for all $z\in \mathbb C$. The function $f$ verifies all your conditions.

Less trivially, try taking $f_\zeta(z)=\exp(\zeta z)$ for a $\zeta\in \mathbb C$ of your choice.

So there is no uniqueness here, you need to add some condition.

You can say for instance that you what that $\exp(z)=e^z$ when $z\in \mathbb R$ where $x\mapsto e^x$ is the usual exponential on $\mathbb R$.

Then you have your uniqueness by the analytic continuation theorem.

Comment: Yes, you were right about the missing hypothesis. By the way, I checked http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.510.5622&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: @user159517 Of course, but he didn't ask for that condition.

Comment: @E.Joseph I can't upvoted with less than 15 of reputation, I'm sorry, but thank you! I edited the post.